# funcion tomas valores sql

Tags: php, sql, function

Hola tengo esta funcion y arroja un 1 que es el registro que esta en la base de datos **

```
function genera_grupo($id,$color,$tamaño){

    $this->query = "  SELECT DISTINCT id,color,tamaño,descripcion
    FROM objetos
    WHERE id='$id'
    AND color='$color'
    AND tamaño='$tamaño' ";

 $rs= $this->get_results_from_query();

 echo "$rs";
  }
```

Lo que quier saber es como puedo imprimir el valor  id, color, tamaño y descripción en la misma función , esto es lo que hace get_results_from_query()

```
protected function get_results_from_query()
{
  if ($this->rows != null) {
    unset($this->rows);
  }
  $result = $this->conn->query($this->query);
  while ($this->rows[] = $result->fetch_assoc());
  $result->close();
  array_pop($this->rows);
}
```

Comment: Eso es php no? Deberias agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje que es

Comment: podria ayudarte si me dices con que base de datos trabajas o que clase ya que no reconosco la funcion `execute_single_query_assignament`

Comment: Pero ¿los métodos `genera_grupo` y `get_results_from_query` están en una misma clase? ¿`$this->rows` representa a un miembro de esa clase? Si es así, puedes hacer simplemente esto: `$arrDatos=array(); while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $arrDatos[]=$row; } $result->close();`  Ahí tendrás en `$arrDatos` un array con cada columna, puedes probarlo haciendo un `var_dump($arrDatos);`  ... OJO: no sé que te pasa con las llaves de apertura y cierre de bloques que no las usas `{  }` correctamente. Tampoco puedes cerrar dentro del `while`, tampoco se entiende lo que representa `$this->rows`

Answer (score 0):

**puedes hacerlo asi:**
ahora puedes acceder a los elementos con `$rs["id"],$rs["color"],$rs["tamaño"]`

> **recomendacion** como buena practica que jamas uses caracter como `ñ` o `acentos` en los nombres de `tablas` ni en los nombres de `variable` asi que deberias cambiarlo antes que todo!

```
function genera_grupo($id,$color,$tamaño){

    $this->query = " SELECT DISTINCT id,color,tamaño,descripcion
    FROM objetos
    WHERE id='$id'
    AND color='$color'
    AND tamaño='$tamaño' ";

 $rs= $this->get_results_from_query();

  //print_r($rs);
return $rs;
  }


protected function get_results_from_query(){
  if ($this->rows != null) {
    unset($this->rows);
  }
  $result = $this->conn->query($this->query);
  while ($this->rows[] = $result->fetch_assoc());
  $result->close();
  return $this->rows;
  //array_pop($this->rows);
}

$miclase = new tuclase();
$rs = $miclase->genera_grupo(1,"verde","grande");
echo $rs["descripcion"];
echo $rs["id"];
```

Comment: no se puede asi es $rs arroja un arreglo

Comment: por supuesto que arroja un arreglo le dijistes `fetch_assoc`, que es un arreglo clave,valor y te puse como accedes a cada uno de los valores lee hijo!

Comment: no puedo comentar array_pop($this->rows); ya que es algo definido que tengo que usar

Comment: entonces as `return array_pop($this->rows);` para que retorne el ultimo elemento y otro `return $this->get_results_from_query();` y asi solo instances tu clase y luego llamas  a los elementos o no se como lo uses!

Comment: me podrías mostrar como, porque al probarlo no me muestra nada, lo agradecería

Comment: ya te agrege un ejemplo solo debes usar el nombre de tu clase y eso!

Comment: no tengo clase objeto  es directamente del query , se puede eso?

Comment: amigo creo que deberias tomar un curso de php! antes de realizar una pregunta ya que estas utilizando programacion orientada a objetos primero empieza con programacion por procedimientos e ir subiendo lo que preguntas es muy avanzado aun para ti aun por lo que veo

Comment: bryro  ya lo resolvi , y no ocupe el curso (Y) gracias